# Open in a new window a document stored in SharePoint in C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

My problem is simple. From an aspx page, I need to open in a new window a document stored in Sharepoint.
To access the document in SharePoint I need to provide credentials.
To open the document in a new window, I need to use javascript.
=> how to link the two ? here is the code :

```
    ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strServerUrl);
    Web currentWeb = ctx.Web;

    ctx.Load(currentWeb);
    ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Login", "Password", "Domain");

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // Here I have access to SharePoint. 
    // I can download the document, but I just want to display it in a new window

    // something is missing here

    string strScript;
    strScript = "window.open('" + myUrltotheDocument + "','','width=800,height=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myPanel, myPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: May be SharePoint is not the right place to store and handle documents, if we cannot retrieve a document knowing its path and the credentials ! I think I should better use an Oracle database with blob fields...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a file using SharePoint Client Object Model with only an absolute url at hand?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the only way I found to open the document in a new window from a .aspx page, is to download the document in a folder on the server, and then, to open a window in javascript with a link to the downloaded document.

```
Uri uriVar = new Uri(strDocUrl);

int intDirectoryIndex = uriVar.LocalPath.LastIndexOf("/");
string strFileName = uriVar.LocalPath.Substring(intDirectoryIndex + 1);

System.Net.WebClient wcVar = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcVar.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Login", "Pwd", "Domain");
string strPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/FileUpload/");
wcVar.DownloadFile(strDocUrl, strPath+strFileName);
string strLocalName = "FileUpload/" + strFileName;

string strScript;
strScript = "window.open('" + strLocalName + "','','width=800,height=800,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(myPanel, myPanel.GetType(), "ShowInfo", strScript, true);
```

I do not consider this as a "nice solution", but it does the job... If someone has a better one, please tell me.

Thank you for the ones who took time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the document is saved in a sharepoint library you can change the library settings so that the document, when clicked, is not downloaded but opened in a new browser window. Have you tried this?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/change-how-to-open-a-document-in-a-library-with-one-click-HA101729873.aspx

Comment: This is an interesting link. In my case, the user does not click directly on the link in SharePoint. The document is accessed by a .Net application, with .aspx pages.

Comment: Check if you have installed office web apps on the sharepoint server.

Comment: Office web apps is not installed on the sharepoint server. We will install it. This, may be, can solve the problem for Office documents, but not for .pdf, jpg,...