# How to get excel file from sharepoint library and write to it programmatically

Tags: excel, file

we would like to

- read an Excel template stored in a SharePoint 2010 library
- create a new Excel file from it
- fill the new Excel file with data programmatically

we tried already Excel Services but however the given MSDN example seems only to work while debugging...!?

what the best practise for the Szenario?
better using cson or serverside ?

[how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url)

Any help appric. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create and modify Office documents you'll need to work with a different technology, Open XML. 
You can download the Open XML SDK here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425

More information is available here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx

I didn't check up on it in detail, but this seems like a fairly decent tutorial using Open XML in SharePoint:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532473.aspx

In your case I'd create a copy of the template and then put some Open XML magic on it.

It may look a little daunting at first, but it's a fairly simple and fun to use.