# SPServices copy list attachments

Tags: 2013, spservices, document-set, attachments

Trying to [follow this post](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/79766) about halfway down to copy attachments from a list item.

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetItem",
    async: false,
    Url:srcUrl,

    completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
        myStream = jQuery(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text();
        console.log(myStream);
    } 
});
```

It doesn't produce any error, but xData.responseXML doesn't include any Stream node and the response text includes

```
<GetItemResult>0</GetItemResult>
```

Which leads me to believe it isn't finding the source file. My source URL is the url that is given when I check it in the item.

`https://site/managedpath/collection/site/Lists/listName/Attachments/itemId/file%20name.pdf`

When I paste the url into the browser it shows me the correct file, so I know there is a file there...

Any ideas on how to get the data stream for this document?

**EDIT**

It does work if I just try and grab a file out of a straight up library. So the problem seems to be with attachments. Where are attachments really stored?

Comment: Attachments are stored in the same location as the SharePoint item forms, in a folder named Attachments. You can browse this structure under "All Files" in Designer. You can retrieve attachment URLs dynamically with SPServices using "GetAttachmentCollection," but it doesn't provide a way to interact with the stream.

Comment: As best I can tell GetAttachmentCollection only returns this list of the URLs. I am able to get the urls in several different ways, but need to interact with the stream. I need to copy the attachments themselves to another location. Why would they behave differently?

Comment: I would recommend asking on the [SPServices discussion board](https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions). Marc is pretty responsive and always interested in new challenges.

Comment: I posted there but haven't heard anything. And I'm hoping that someone might have a non-SP Services way of doing it. It seems like this should be a possible thing.

Comment: I saw you commented on a thread from 2010. I'd create a new thread.

Have you seen the first answer on this question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62087/how-to-get-a-file-using-sharepoint-client-object-model-with-only-an-absolute-url

Comment: Yes I realized adding to an old thread might not get any notice, so I created a new one. The first answer on that question isn't using javascript, I'm not sure how I could adapt that to our situation.